# Show Radio buttons side by side

Tags: html, css, user-interface, siebel

I am working on Siebel Smartscript. I want to show the radio button side by side, but by default they are coming after a line break as shown below:
[image]

The html is dynamically generated via swt. The part of the section where radio button is present is below:

```
<swe:control id="SSQuestion">
  <table valign="top" width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="AppletBack">
    <tr>
        <td width=20%>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width=75%>
            <span class="questLabel" align="swe:this.TextAlignment">
            <swe:this property="DisplayName"/>
            <swe:this property="RequiredIndicator"/>
            </span><br>
            <span class="scField" align="swe:this.TextAlignment">
                <swe:this property="FormattedHtml"/></span>         
        </td>
        <td width="5%">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</swe:control>
```

The below is what the above is looking like at runtime:

```
<SPAN id=SSQuestionList><TABLE class=AppletBack border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=2 width="100%" valign="top">
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD width="20%">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD width="75%"><SPAN class=questLabel><SPAN id=s_2_1_7_0_d><B>Date of Birth<B></B></B></SPAN><SPAN id=s_2_1_7_0_r>&nbsp;</SPAN></SPAN><BR><SPAN class=scField>
<DIV id=s_2_1_7_0_ss>
<OBJECT style="HEIGHT: 49px" id=s_2_1_7_0 tabIndex=2997 classid=CLSID:07903935-5554-4827-87bf-f195bef987f7 width=500 height=20></OBJECT></DIV></SPAN></TD>
<TD width="5%">&nbsp;</TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
<SCRIPT defer>
SWEWriteInnerHTML(this.document.getElementById('s_2_1_7_0_ss'),'<object id=s_2_1_7_0 CLASSID="CLSID:07903935-5554-4827-87bf-f195bef987f7" HEIGHT=20 WIDTH=500></object>');
</SCRIPT>
</SPAN>
```

This is the line which is selecting the area of radio button:

```
SWEWriteInnerHTML(this.document.getElementById('s_2_1_7_0_ss'),'<object id=s_2_1_7_0 CLASSID="CLSID:07903935-5554-4827-87bf-f195bef987f7" HEIGHT=20 WIDTH=500></object>');
```

But i am not sure how to alter it. I have tried css property inline, but to no avail. Please suggest.

Comment: It would be helpful to have a fiddle or something where it's possible to inspect the html.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML you see is generated inside the Siebel HI application. It uses Active X controls to show the UI objects such as the radio button. I know of no way to alter the positioning of the options while remaining within the confines of Siebel HI. The newer Open UI framework generates standard HI for smart scripts which would in turn allow you to achieve your requirement.